# Looking for duplicate images in multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below HTML I'm trying to loop through using jQuery's .each() method:

```
<div id="currentOrder" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 79px; max-height: none; height: auto;">

<div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product3">
    <div class="fltLeft numAmt3">
        <span id="builtVehNum" class="hidden"><span>X</span></span>
    </div>
     <div class="fltLeft positionRelative name3">
        <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment" src="../images/wheels1.png">
        <img class="pattern patternInShipment" src="../images/checkerboard1192015.png">
        <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment" src="../images/car1192015.png" style="">
     </div>
     <div class="fltRight recycle hidden" id="removeHidden3">:)</div>
     <div class="fltRight removeX">–</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>

<div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product4">
    <div class="fltLeft numAmt4">
        <span id="builtVehNum" class="hidden"><span>X</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fltLeft positionRelative name4">
        <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment" src="../images/wheels2.png">
        <img class="pattern patternInShipment" src="../images/fire1192015.png">
        <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment" src="../images/truck1192015.png" style="">
     </div>
     <div class="fltRight recycle hidden" id="removeHidden4">:)</div>
     <div class="fltRight removeX">–</div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>

<div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product5">
    <div class="fltLeft numAmt5"><span id="builtVehNum" class="hidden"><span>X</span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="fltLeft positionRelative name5">
        <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment" src="../images/wheels3.png">
        <img class="pattern patternInShipment" src="../images/squiggle1192015.png">
        <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment" src="../images/van1192015.png" style="">
    </div>
    <div class="fltRight recycle hidden" id="removeHidden5">:)</div>
    <div class="fltRight removeX">–</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
 </div>

<div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product6">
    <div class="fltLeft numAmt6"><span id="builtVehNum" class="hidden"><span>X</span></span>
</div>
<div class="fltLeft positionRelative name6">
    <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment" src="../images/wheels1.png">
    <img class="pattern patternInShipment" src="../images/checkerboard1192015.png">
    <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment" src="../images/car1192015.png" style="">
</div>
    <div class="fltRight recycle hidden" id="removeHidden6">:)</div>
    <div class="fltRight removeX">–</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I'm attempting to look through all of the div containers with a class of .vehiclesInBox and compare the image sources in them.  If there is an exact match of all three images, remove the newest duplicate div#product(x), and add a number counter to the matched container in span#builtVehNum.  My jQuery is below:

```
 $("#currentOrder .vehiclesInBox").each(function() {
        var jaVehicle = $(this).find("img.vehicleInShipment").attr("src")
        var jaWheel = $(this).find("img.wheelsInShipment").attr("src")
        var jaPattern = $(this).find("img.patternInShipment").attr("src")

        });
```

I'm confused as to what the next step would be?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: So if 2 and 6, 4 and 5 are duplicates. What all do you want to remove?

Comment: I would only want to remove the last div listed with an id of product(x) that had all three exact images (img.vehicleInShpment, img.WheelsInShipment and img.patternInShipment) to another div#product(x) above it.  Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: My understanding is that you have products, you want to see if there are duplicate products by comparing their images. If there are duplicate products you want to remove the newest one? But the images are not what you are trying to remove they are just your source of comparison for products? Is this really the only way you can compare products? they dont have a name or an ID or something that better identifies them than their images?

Comment: IDs.are.unique. dont give multiple elements the same id `builtVehNum`

Comment: @Dustin Poissant, you are correct, I'd be comparing the products by the source of the images.  At this point, I don't have another name or ID that better identifies them.  That's something I can look into incorporating.  I was hoping to just compare off of the image source.  Alex, thanks for catching that.  I'll switch that to a class instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not yet adding the counter, but here you have a rough selection logic:

```
$("#currentOrder .vehiclesInBox").each(function() {
  var cont = $(this),
    images = cont.find('img'),
    srcs = new Array(images.eq(0).attr('src'), images.eq(1).attr('src'), images.eq(2).attr('src')),
    matchings = $("#currentOrder .vehiclesInBox").filter(function() {
        return $(this).find('img[src="' + srcs[0] + '"]').length && $(this).find('img[src="' + srcs[1] + '"]').length && $(this).find('img[src="' + srcs[2] + '"]').length;
    });

    if (matchings.length > 1) {
        matchings.filter(':last').fadeTo(500, .5);
    }

});
```

Replace `fadeTo(500, .5);` with `remove();`.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/231wtasa/)

Comment: Thanks!  this got me pretty close to what I needed, working on the counter portion now.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it something like this:

1. Loop over each product and then for each product, loop over its images.
2. Within the loop, you'll create an array to keep track of all image sources. Each time you encounter a new image, check if its source already exists in the array. If it does not, add it. If if DOES, add one to our duplicateCounter.
3. At the end, check if the duplicateCounter is equal to 3 (in other words, you have three matching image sources).
4. If so, remove the current product

See code below (run to see it in action):

```js
function removeDuplicates() {

  var imgSources = []; // empty array to hold image sources for comparison
  var duplicateCounter; // counter to keep track of how many duplicate image sources found
  var src;

  // Loop over each product
  $("#currentOrder .vehiclesInBox").each(function() {

    // Reset the duplicate counter to zero for each new product
    duplicateCounter = 0;

    // Loop over the current product's images
    $(this).find('img').each(function() {

      src = $(this).attr('src');

      // Check if the current image source exists in the image source array. 
      // If it does, increment the counter by one.
      if ($.inArray(src, imgSources) > -1) {
        duplicateCounter++;
      } else {
        // If it doesn't already exist in the array, add it
        imgSources.push(src);
      }

    });

    // Now that we've looped through all the images for the current product, check if the duplicate count is 3. If so, remove the product.
    if (duplicateCounter === 3) {
      $(this).remove();
    }

  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Call the function on document ready
  removeDuplicates();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="currentOrder" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 79px; max-height: none; height: auto;">

    <div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product3">
      <div>Product 3</div>

      <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment" src="../images/wheels1.png">
      <img class="pattern patternInShipment" src="../images/checkerboard1192015.png">
      <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment" src="../images/car1192015.png" style="">
    </div>

    <div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product4">
      <div>Product 4</div>
      <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment" src="../images/wheels2.png">
      <img class="pattern patternInShipment" src="../images/fire1192015.png">
      <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment" src="../images/truck1192015.png" style="">
    </div>

    <div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product5">
      <div>Product 5</div>
      <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment" src="../images/wheels3.png">
      <img class="pattern patternInShipment" src="../images/squiggle1192015.png">
      <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment" src="../images/van1192015.png" style="">
    </div>

    <div class="vehiclesInBox" id="product6">
      <div>Product 6 (this one has duplicate images and will be removed...)</div>
      <img class="wheelThmbs wheelsInShipment" src="../images/wheels1.png">
      <img class="pattern patternInShipment" src="../images/checkerboard1192015.png">
      <img class="vehicle vehicleInShipment" src="../images/car1192015.png" style="">
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Devorah, thanks for the comment!  I'll give this a shot and update the post.

Comment: Hope it helped! You can rerun this function if you subsequently add another product and need to re-check for duplicates. It will also catch and remove multiple products that have duplicate images.